# How to install PLV8 on Windows?

Tags: windows, postgresql

I'm trying to install this on my PostgreSQL server
http://code.google.com/p/plv8js/wiki/PLV8
the docs looks great but the problem is they are for linux and my company only have access to a Windows Server.
Someone can tell me how to install PLV8 on Windows please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The kind folks at Postgres Online Journal have pre-compiled the binaries for PLV8 for Windows

9.6: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/367-PLV8-binaries-for-PostgreSQL-9.6-windows-both-32-bit-and-64-bit.html

9.5: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/360-PLV8-binaries-for-PostgreSQL-9.5-windows-both-32-bit-and-64-bit.html

9.4: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/341-PLV8-binaries-for-PostgreSQL-9.4-windows-both-32-bit-and-64-bit.html

9.3: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/305-PostgreSQL-9.3-extension-treats-for-windows-users-plV8.html

9.2: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/280-PLV8-1.3-windows-binaries-for-PostgreSQL-9.2.html

Comment: Here's the page to keep track of for latest updates on these extensions: http://www.postgresonline.com/winextensions.php

Comment: 10: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/379-PLV8-binaries-for-PostgreSQL-10-windows-both-32-bit-and-64-bit.html

Answer (score 0):

We managed to build it on windows and are testing it now.  We'll provide binaries for it once we can be sure we can retrace our steps.

We built under Mingw64 chain (and for compiling v8 had to use scons instead of recommended glyph (or whatever that is) and had to change a couple of things in the script to make it work as well.  I have it just for 32-bit windows (seems to work fine on my PostgreSQL EnterpriseDb install at first blush - loads and a sample stored proc seemed to work fine).  I'm going to try next for 64-bit windows.

Other issue is the compressed files don't work.  You have to go to the git one directly.

Keep your eyes focused on our site :)
UPDATE: We have instructions up and also binaries if you want to try
http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/260-Building-on-MingW-and-deploying-on-VC-compiled-PostgreSQL-Why-and-Why-not.html

Answer (score -1):

If you're not comfortable building PostgreSQL itself from source on Windows, then building this extension then I'd just forget about it. This is an extension that is still in the early stages and presumably subject to regular change and not tested in the real world to anywhere near the level of PostgreSQL itself or even most optional extensions. It is interesting though, isn't it?

Comment: You may wish to delete this answer. It's out of date, as Windows binaries are now available.