# How to install plv8 in postgresql 12 on Windows10?

Tags: postgresql, plv8

I have followed instruction given in [How to install PLV8 on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076030/how-to-install-plv8-on-windows) and [Can't create extensions plv8 postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680574/cant-create-extensions-plv8-postgresql) questions, but I am getting below error:

> ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/12/lib/plv8.dll": The specified procedure could not be found.
>   SQL state: 58P01

Comment: You should open an issue with the software.

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious: you **do** have the file `C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/12/lib/plv8.dll`? Did you download the Postgres 12 binaries from XTuple?

Comment: yes I o have dll files in correct position.. No I am not using XTuple